# How do I install Darwin 13 on OS X 10.9.1?

Tags: macos, darwin

I've recently bought a MacBook with OS X 10.9 and I've just updated it to 10.9.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 64-bit).

I'd like to install the version 13 of Darwin.

I've done everything proposed by [this website](http://shantonu.blogspot.be/2013/10/building-xnu-for-os-x-109-mavericks.html), but when I try to `make` xnu, I have this error message:

```
Generating libkern/version.h from /Users/xxxx/Downloads/xnu-2422.1.72/libkern/libkern/version.h.template
install: target ‘version.h’ is not a directory
make[5]: *** [version.h] Error 1
make[4]: *** [build_exporthdrs_mi] Error 2
make[3]: *** [build_exporthdrs_mi_recurse_into_libkern] Error 2
make[2]: *** [build_exporthdrs_mi_recurse_into_libkern] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [build_exporthdrs_mi_bootstrap_RELEASE^X86_64^NONE] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo make`?

Comment: I've just tried with sudo. I'm getting the same error messages

Comment: @Tetraodienne, you ***"tried with `sudo`"*** — with `sudo make` or `sudo make ARCH_CONFIGS=X86_64 KERNEL_CONFIGS=RELEASE`? Just to be clear, daviesgeek is stating `sudo make` by itself. Also, ensure you're in the `xnu-2422.1.72` directory to execute the command.

Comment: @l'L'l I've tried both `sudo make` and `sudo make ARCH_CONFIGS=X86_64 KERNEL_CONFIGS=RELEASE`. And yes, I'm sure I've executed these commands in the `xnu-2422.1.72`directory.

Comment: @Tetraodienne, Ah good, just making sure. It could be something is amiss with the instructions you're using. One more question, do have the xcode command line tools installed?

Comment: Ok, so the problem is somewhere with my bash (I've brewed some GNU utils). So, I've used `zsh` and the `make` worked great!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just in the OPs setup and so no use to anyone else

Comment: @Mark We do have these kind of questions now and then, and while I agree that the case is very specific, the answer (try another shell) might be of value for others running into compile issues of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is somewhere with my bash (I've brewed some GNU utils, it is maybe it). So, I've used zsh and the `make`command compiled great!